# JavaScript - Declared variable not defined error when function is run

Tags: javascript, calculator

I'm trying to create a calculator that can say how many friday the 13th's there are in a year by typing a year in an input and then clicking the button - an alert() will appear with the result:

```html
<script>
    function Fridaythe13(j) {
        var count = document.getElementById('year').value;
        var count = 0;
        for (var month=0; month<12; month++) {
            var d = new Date(j,month,13);
            if(d.getDay() == 5){
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;                            
    }

    document.getElementById("run").addEventListener("click", function(){
        alert(Fridaythe13(count));
    })
</script>

<input type="text" name="year" id="year" />
<section class="material">
    <div class="actions">
        <button type="button" id="run">Run</button>
    </div>
</section>
```

When I click on the button, it says that the count variable is not defined but I declared it with the input ('year'), so I don't understand... Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You are declaring `count` twice. You should change the name of one of the variables. Looks like you might want to rename the first one to `j`...

Comment: Please consider rereading your code before posting it. And format it appropriately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some of your logic was broken, here is a working example.

First, you were defining the variable `count` twice in your function.

Also, from your click handler, you were passing an argument `count` to your inner function but this variable was not declared either.

Consider using better names for your variables. For example `year` instead of `j`.

Also prefer the use of `let/const` to `var` for declaring variables.

```js
function fridayThe13(year) {
    let count = 0;
    for (let month = 0; month < 12; month++) {
      const date = new Date(year, month, 13);
      if (date.getDay() == 5) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    return count;                            
}

document.getElementById("run").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const year = document.getElementById('year').value;
  alert(fridayThe13(year));
})
```

```html
<input type="text" name="year" id="year" />
<section class="material">
  <div class="actions">
    <button type="button" id="run">Run</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Here is a shorter way to do it, using functional style with a `map` and `reduce` to sum the values:

```
function fridayThe13(year) {
    return [...Array(12).keys()] // [0, 1, 2,... 11]
        .map(month => new Date(year, month, 13).getDay() == 5)
        .reduce((accum, val) => accum += val, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable count is defined (twice as @GetOffMyLawn points out) within the function `Fridaythe13`, and the alert is attempting to access it outside of that function.  I believe you intended your code to look like this:

```
var count = document.getElementById('year').value;

function Fridaythe13(j) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var month = 0; month < 12; month++) {
    var d = new Date(j, month, 13);
    if (d.getDay() == 5) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

document.getElementById("run").addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert(Fridaythe13(count));
})
```

But just to keep from getting confused, I'd recommend changing the first declared `count` variable to a different variable name.  Perhaps something like this:

```
var thisYear = document.getElementById('year').value;

function Fridaythe13(j) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var month = 0; month < 12; month++) {
    var d = new Date(j, month, 13);
    if (d.getDay() == 5) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

document.getElementById("run").addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert(Fridaythe13(thisYear));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your count declared within the wrong function (`document.getElementById('year').value`). Move it to the other function and it will work.

```js
function Fridaythe13(j) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var month = 0; month < 12; month++) {
    var d = new Date(j, month, 13);
    if (d.getDay() == 5) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

document.getElementById("run").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var count = document.getElementById('year').value;
  alert(Fridaythe13(count));
})
```

```html
<input type="text" name="year" id="year" />
<section class="material">
  <div class="actions">
    <button type="button" id="run">Run</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You define count twice. Move the first declaration and rename it.

```
     <script>
     function Fridaythe13(year) {
            var count = 0;
            for (var month=0; month<12; month++) {
                var d = new Date(year,month,13);
                if(d.getDay() == 5){
                  count++;
                }
            }
            return count;                            
        }

        document.getElementById("run").addEventListener("click", function 
        (){
            var selected_year = document.getElementById('year').value;

            alert(Fridaythe13(selected_year));
        })
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `map()` function to collect all the 13'th days of each month, and then filter for only the Fridays.

```js
const count = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
                   .map(m=>new Date(2019,m,13).getDay())
                   .filter(d=>d==5)
                   .length;
console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Recognizing that Fri 13 means Sunday the 1st, and using year and month offsets, it's possible to do this arithmetically without reference to date objects (note: this version works only on the gregorian calendar and in years greater than 0)

```
function countFri13(year) {
  var count = 0;
  const leapYear = (year % 4 && !((year % 100) && !(year % 400)))
  var yearOffset = (1 + 5 * ((year - 1) % 4) + 4 * ((year - 1) % 100) + 6 * ((year - 1) % 400)) % 7;
  if (leapYear) {
    var monthOffsets = [0, 3, 4, 0, 2, 5, 0, 3, 6, 1, 4, 5]
  } else {
    monthOffsets = ([0, 3, 3, 6, 1, 4, 6, 2, 5, 0, 3, 4])
  }
  for (var month = 0; month < 12; month++) {
    if ((yearOffset + monthOffsets[month]) %  7 === 0) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

// in ES6...

function countFri13es6(year) {
  let count = 0,
    monthOffsets = [];
  const yearOffset = (1 + 5 * ((year - 1) % 4) + 4 * ((year - 1) % 100) + 6 * ((year - 1) % 400)) % 7;
  (year % 4 && !((year % 100) && !(year % 400))) ? monthOffsets = [0, 3, 4, 0, 2, 5, 0, 3, 6, 1, 4, 5]: monthOffsets = ([0, 3, 3, 6, 1, 4, 6, 2, 5, 0, 3, 4])
  for (var month = 0; month < 12; month++) {
    if ((yearOffset + monthOffsets[month]) % 7 === 0) count++;
  }
  return count;
}
```